# change growl message color

Tags: colors, primefaces, growl

I have a common css for all the pages in my application called `growl.css`...

I have

```
.ui-growl{
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      margin-top: -50px;
      margin-left: -100px;    
      }
```

How do I change the background color of the growl message.  Inserting color and `background-color` didn't change a thing. Thanks

Comment: .ui-growl-item-container { background-image: url('./imgs/background.jpg'); } this is to set image , try using color or background-color

Comment: inserting background-color does work, just had to clear out recent history :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-growl-item-container { background-image: url('./imgs/background.jpg'); }
```

this is to set image , try using color or background-color